# Which characters are not valid in XML text

Tags: xml, text

Perhaps this question has already been answered but I have spent quite a lot of time trying to find it...
In my application, I store a sequence of XML text values, each of which need to be terminated by more than one "special Char" (such as NULL), so that having this sequence I can retrieve all texts.
Thus, I am looking for the set of chars which can not be used within the XML document text values. 
http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Char appears to be confusing: "Document authors are encouraged to avoid "compatibility characters", as defined in section 2.3 of [Unicode]. The characters defined in the following ranges are also discouraged..."
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As it says: Compatability characters will be tolerated, but XML strongly recommends that you avoid them. Other characters, specifically including null, are explicitly forbidden in XML 1.0.

For an explanation of why, I ***highly*** recommend looking at [The Annotated XML 1.0 Recommendation](http://www.xml.com/axml/testaxml.htm), which provides detailed notes on the XML Recommendation's rationalle and intent from one of its primary authors.

XML 1.1 changed the rules and explicitly permits some characters that were explicitly forbidden in 1.0. Unfortunately nobody has invested the work to create an Annotated version of the XML 1.1 REC... and not all software supports XML 1.1, so unless you have a Good Reason for doing otherwise I would recommend sticking with XML 1.0 for maximum compatibility. (NULL is still forbidden in XML 1.1, I believe, so it wouldn't help in your case.)

Find another representation of NULL which your application can translate after reading the XML, or (better) another way of delimiting your values that is more in keeping with XML's design.

Comment: Thanks, you said: In my application, I store a sequence of XML text values, each of which need to be terminated by more than one "special Char" (such as NULL), so that having this sequence I can retrieve all texts

Comment: I'm not sure why you aren't using XML structure itself to delimit each of those text values...? If you're using XML, you might as well use XML.

Comment: I work on XML compression, where the structure is separated from data and can't use what you have suggested. Thus, for a good reason data are stored separately and the structure can't "separate" them.

Comment: Right. I'm not going to get into that argument. Good luck with it.